# Trouble with google OAuth 2.0 in express

Tags: node.js, express, google-oauth

I am trying to load the google consent screen and login with google OAuth 2.0.

When clicking on the "Sign up with Google" button the server gets hung up and I'm not sure where the problem lies.

Here is my app.js code:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require("express")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const ejs = require("ejs")
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const session = require("express-session")
const passport = require("passport")
const passportLoacalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose")
const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy
const findOrCreate = require("mongoose-findorcreate")

const app = express()

app.use(express.static("public"))
app.set("view engine", "ejs")
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(session({
    secret: "Our little secret"
    , resave: false
    , saveUninitialized: false
}))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/userDB")

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String
    , password: String
})

userSchema.plugin(passportLoacalMongoose)
userSchema.plugin(findOrCreate)

const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema)

passport.use(User.createStrategy())
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser())
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser())

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/secrets"
},
    function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
        User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
            return cb(err, user);
        });
    }
));

app.route("/")
    .get((req, res) => {
        res.render("home")
    })

app.route("/auth/google")
    .get((req, res) => {
        passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile"] })
    })

app.route("/register")
    .get((req, res) => {
        res.render("register")
    })
    .post((req, res) => {
        User.register({ username: req.body.username }, req.body.password, (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
                res.redirect("/register")
            } else {
                passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, () => {
                    res.redirect("/secrets")
                })
            }
        })
    })

app.route("/login")
    .get((req, res) => {
        res.render("login")
    })
    .post((req, res) => {
        const user = new User({
            username: req.body.username
            , password: req.body.password
        })

        req.login(user, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, () => {
                    res.redirect("/secrets")
                })
            }
        })
    })

app.route("/secrets")
    .get((req, res) => {
        if (req.isAuthenticated) {
            res.render("secrets")
        } else {
            res.redirect("/login")
        }
    })

app.route("/logout")
    .get((req, res) => {
        req.logout((err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        })
        res.redirect("/")
    })

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server started on port 3000.")
})
```

Here is a picture of the issue:

[image: Register Screen]

I have tried rewriting the code to make sure there are no syntax errors or typos. What could be the problem?

Comment: #1 What do you me by **the server gets hung up**? Do you have an screenshot or log of the error? #2 When you press the google login button, inspect the browser and/or press the escape key to stop the  302 redirect and share us the url (obfuscating your client_d)

Comment: I don't recieve an error. It gets stuck in a infinite loading loop. The URL after pressing the esc key is http://localhost:3000/register. Does this mean that the callbackURL is not valid?

Comment: #1 A 302 it is too fast. Check again. First link should be a huge google url in which the client_id is. Then the  `localhost:3000/register`. If the google url is not being triggered , that could be the error. #2 Infinite loop is classic in the first oauth2 login attempts. It is because if login was not performed (google special variable saved in session), express redirect the use to the login, login to google, google success login to register , register to login, etc Check the log and share the error : https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EVLY.png

Comment: It does not flash to any url besides the one I provided and the log has no errors. https://i.imgur.com/6Z6bgL4.png

Comment: Yeah, the `/register` post route only gets called when manually registering an email and password. The `/auth/google` route is what gets called when clicking on the Sign up with google button. https://i.imgur.com/GxZSXrc.png

Comment: I found the error. I just needed to change the `.get` in the `/auth/google` route to :
`.get(passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile"] }))`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The way to use it is to have passport.authenticate and no callback is needed.

```
app.route("/auth/google")
    .get(passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile"] }))
```